# JQuery UI Range Slider Update Values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have an implementation of a JQuery UI Range slider:

```
$(function() {
$("#test").val(0);
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 1,
    max: 24,
    values: [ 10, 15 ],
    create: function(event, ui){

       },
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $( "#amount" ).val( "" + ui.values[ 0 ] +":00" + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]+":00" );
    }
});

$( "#amount" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    ":00 - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + ":00");

$( "#check" ).button();
$( "#format" ).buttonset();
});
```

I want to access the `values` of the slider outside these functions. aka `ui.values[ 0 ]` and `ui.values[ 1 ]`. However if I create some kind of global variable outside this block and update the variable in `$( "#slider-range" ).slider({slide:})` it doesn't overwrite it and therefore it doesn't update when the user uses the slider. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your goal here.  Why do you need to use `ui.values[0]` when your external functions can see `$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )` just fine?

Comment: I've tried accessing $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) with an external function and displaying it in a text box but it only shows the start value and doesn't update as I move the slider

Comment: Why can't you set the value of the textbox from within the `slide` function?  Since that's the effect you want, right?  You want to update the textbox as the slider slides.

Comment: Is `#amount` the textbox you're trying to set?  Because if it is, you're already using the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

set a hidden variable in your form like 
    
and then update it using slide function 
    slide:function (event,ui)
    {
    document.getElementById("testH").value=$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
    }